# Может ли придаточное зависеть от обращения?

Tags: синтаксис

Предложение: Ребята, которые едут на экскурсию, соберитесь возле кабинета директора! Рассуждаю так: ребята - это обращение. (Ребята, соберитесь!). Получается, что придаточное зависит от обращения? Или входит в обращение?

Answer (score 3):

Предложение разговорного стиля, что ж...

Думаю, что обращение здесь **ребята, которые едут на экскурсию**, а не **ребята**.

Comment: Заменим придаточное на Причастный оборот, будет 
не разговорный стиль. Получится, что оборот зависит 
от обращения.

Answer (score 1):

Обращения бывают распространенные и нераспространенные.  В качестве распространителей используются определения, приложения, определительные обороты, придаточные определительные  предложения, например:  Звёзды, таящие мысли глубокие, силой какою вы душу пленяете?